# Convert HTML Anchors to Markdown Link?

Tags: javascript

How can I convert HTML anchors :

```
<a href="https://www.google.com">I'm an inline-style link</a>
```

Markdown link:

```
[I'm an inline-style link](https://www.google.com)
```

I think I will need Regex to do it.

Comment: I just use the DOM attributes to solve the problem

Answer (score 2):

I have got it working using regex and JS replace function.

```
HTMLAnchor.replace(/<a.*?href="(.*?)".*?>(.*?)<\/a>/g, "[$2]($1)")
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
//function takes in a dom element and returns markdown
function convertHref(aDomElem){
  //it'll work for your example at least :D
  return `(${aDomElem.innerText})[${aDomElem.href}]`
}
var a=document.getElementById('a')
console.log(convertHref(a))
```

```html
<a id="a" href="https://www.google.com">I'm an inline-style link</a>
```